# IIS7 VPS Hosting Server Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have just registered a Windows 2008 VPS hosting account which I plan on running a couple of web sites on. In the past I have just used shared hosting in which everything is set up for me, so need a few pointers.

1. When I register a new domain it asks for a couple of name servers. How do I set this up on my server? Can I just give it the IP address of the VPS server? Do I have to register some web sites with ns1, ns2 host headers in IIS? It's all a bit confusing when never done before.
2. I have two web sites I plan on hosting. I configured both in IIS with a different IP address (the VPS plan has 2) but when trying to access the site via IP it always displays the default web site. If I turn off the default web site it just 404's. Is there any simple tutorials for setting up a couple of sites from scratch.

Comment: I removed teh VPS tag because, seriously, NOTHING in there is VPS specific. A VPS is a PS - it is like any physical server for you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer point 1, the registrar should have nameservers available - have them point to the IP address of the VPS you've just acquired.

Point 2 - I'm sure there are a bunch of good IIS tutorials out there. I'd love to be shown some :)

Answer (score 0):

Point 1: As Warren said your DNS registrar should have DNS servers. Just point the DNS records you make to the IP(s) of your VPS in their management portal. one tip if i where you i would look into 'host headers' instead of individual IP addrsses for each site.

Point 2: There is some very solid info on the IIS learning portal i suggest you start there if you are looking for tutorials or howto's.

http://learn.iis.net/